# UWP x:Bind updates when bound to ObservableCollection but not to custom INotifyCollectionChanged implementaion

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection, xbind

In my UWP app there is a ListBox which lists the recently used files. I store that information in an ObservableCollection and bind it to the ItemsSource property of the ListBox. The updating works as expected.

However if I switch from ObservableCollection to SmartList (which is a custom list that implements INotifyCollectionChanged) the binding doesn't work anymore. I used this class often in WPF applications and it always worked well. I also have unit tests that test the CollecionChanged event.

Is there a difference between x:Bind and Binding in terms of UpdateTriggers or does someone know what I am missing here?

**// Update**

Here is the Code from `SmartList<T>`:

```
public class SmartList<T> : SmartCollectionBase<T>, IList<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public override bool IsReadOnly => false;
    public override int Count => list.Count;

    private List<T> list;


    public SmartList()
    {
        list = new List<T>();
    }

    public SmartList(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        list = new List<T>(collection);
    }

    public SmartList(int capacity)
    {
        list = new List<T>(capacity);
    }

    public override IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public override void Add(T item)
    {
        list.Add(item);
        OnItemsAdded(new SmartListChangedEventArgs(new SmartChange(item, list.Count - 1, ChangeType.Added)));
        NotifyCountChange();
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        if (!items.Any())
            return;

        var changes = new List<SmartChange>();
        var idx = list.Count;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            list.Add(item);
            changes.Add(new SmartChange(item, idx, ChangeType.Added));
            idx++;
        }
        OnItemsAdded(new SmartListChangedEventArgs(changes));
        NotifyCountChange();
    }

    public void AddRange(params T[] items)
    {
        AddRange((IEnumerable<T>) items);
        NotifyCountChange();
    }

    public override void Clear()
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
            return;

        var old = list;
        list = new List<T>(list.Capacity);
        OnItemsRemoved(new SmartListChangedEventArgs(old.Select((c, i) => new SmartChange(c, i, ChangeType.Removed))));
        NotifyCountChange();
    }

    public override bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return list.Contains(item);
    }

    public override void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public override bool Remove(T item)
    {
        int idx = IndexOf(item);

        if (idx == -1)
            return false;

        RemoveAt(idx);
        NotifyCountChange();
        return true;
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return list.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        list.Insert(index, item);
        OnItemsAdded(new SmartListChangedEventArgs(new SmartChange(item, index, ChangeType.Added)));
        NotifyCountChange();
    }

    public void InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        if (index > list.Count || index < 0)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

        if (!items.Any())
            return;

        var changes = items.Select((item, i) => new SmartChange(item, index + i, ChangeType.Added));
        list.InsertRange(index, items);

        OnItemsAdded(new SmartListChangedEventArgs(changes));
        NotifyCountChange();
    }

    public void InsertRange(int index, params T[] items)
    {
        InsertRange(index, (IEnumerable<T>) items);
        NotifyCountChange();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        var item = list[index];
        list.RemoveAt(index);
        OnItemsRemoved(new SmartListChangedEventArgs(new SmartChange(item, index, ChangeType.Removed)));
        NotifyCountChange();
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return list[index]; }
        set
        {
            var old = list[index];
            if (ReferenceEquals(old, value))
                return;

            list[index] = value;
            OnItemsReplaced(new SmartListChangedEventArgs(new SmartChange(old, index, ChangeType.Removed), new SmartChange(value, index, ChangeType.Added)));
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void NotifyCountChange()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));
    }
```

And its base class:

```
public abstract class SmartCollectionBase<T> : ISmartCollection<T>
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    public event EventHandler<SmartListChangedEventArgs> ItemsAdded;
    public event EventHandler<SmartListChangedEventArgs> ItemsRemoved;
    public event EventHandler<SmartListChangedEventArgs> ItemsMoved;
    public event EventHandler<SmartListChangedEventArgs> ItemsReplaced;
    public event EventHandler<SmartListChangedEventArgs> ItemsChanged;

    public abstract IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
    public abstract void Add(T item);
    public abstract void Clear();
    public abstract bool Contains(T item);
    public abstract void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex);
    public abstract bool Remove(T item);
    public abstract int Count { get; }
    public abstract bool IsReadOnly { get; }


    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnItemsAdded(SmartListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsAdded?.Invoke(this, e);
        OnItemsChanged(e);

        if (MustInvokeINotifyCollectionChanged())
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, e.Changes.Select(c => c.Change).ToList()));
    }

    protected virtual void OnItemsRemoved(SmartListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsRemoved?.Invoke(this, e);
        OnItemsChanged(e);

        if (MustInvokeINotifyCollectionChanged())
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, e.Changes.Select(c => c.Change).ToList(), e.Changes[0].Index));
    }

    protected virtual void OnItemsMoved(SmartListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsMoved?.Invoke(this, e);
        OnItemsChanged(e);

        if (MustInvokeINotifyCollectionChanged())
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move, e.Changes.Select(c => c.Change).ToList(), e.Changes[0].Index, e.Changes[0].OldIndex));
    }

    protected virtual void OnItemsReplaced(SmartListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsReplaced?.Invoke(this, e);
        OnItemsChanged(e);

        if (MustInvokeINotifyCollectionChanged())
        {
            var changes = e.Changes.GroupBy(c => c.ChangeType).OrderBy(g => g.Key).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
            if (changes.Count != 2 || changes[0].Count != changes[1].Count)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("A replace operation must have an eqaul amount of added and removed items");
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, changes[0], changes[1]));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnItemsChanged(SmartListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private bool MustInvokeINotifyCollectionChanged()
    {
        return CollectionChanged != null;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(", ", "{0}");
    }

    public string ToString(string seperator, string format)
    {
        return this.Stringify(seperator, format);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `SmartList` implement `IList` ?

Comment: @Laith It implements `IList<T>`. The full header is `public class SmartList<T> : ICollection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifySmartListChanged, IList<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: @Timo Since I see you are using INotifyCollectionChanged I deleted my answer.  Apologies... Can you please post the code to SmartList so that I may see if you're implementing it correctly?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII No Worries. I could post the code but that would involve the SmartList<T>, its base class, an interface and a bunch of custom EventArgs. As I said, I already used the SmartList<T> in various WPF applications and it always worked without any problems

Comment: @Timo Well, with my experience, especially today, I have overlooked something simple when transporting my code.  It may just be that you've overlooked something small.  Is this the same type used now in UWP or is it re-written or copied?  I spend 3 hours today because I overlooked an attribute when swapping libraries to UWP and didn't realize it.  It may be possible but hard to imagine UWP binding to ObservableCollection and not INotifyCollectionChanged but it may be.  Might want to look at the source.  I'm digging for you though.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I've updated the question

Comment: @Timo Thanks Timo, indeed it does look correct from my skimming... I'm digging into the x:Bind for UWP but you said an ObservableCollection does work properly correct?  Could you write code in your app, in the view, to listen to the collectionchanged event and place a break point to see if it's indeed firing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141487/discussion-between-michael-puckett-ii-and-timo).

Comment: Short update: it seems like binding to IEnumerable does not work either. If I reassign the entire list (this time as IEnumerable) the ListBox doesn't update its content. But if I change to List<T> the content is updated on reassignment. Looks like there is a serious issue somewhere